# Azure web app Back limit exceeded

Tags: azure, database-backups, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App configured for Backups. It runs once a day and backup both website and database". I have checked the database size is just 170MB but now during taking backup I am facing error "The website + database size exceeds the 10 GB limit for backups. Your content size is 10 GB".

Answer (score 1):

It necessarily need not be your Database that can cause the size to exceed. The Logfiles folder can also contributes to the size. If you are sure that the Database is not at fault, then look at the other areas that can cause the size to bloat. You can determine folder content size using the  **Azure Web Apps Disk Usage** Site Extension.

This is how it looks like:
[image: Disk Usage]

**Installing the Site Extension:**

- Browse the Kudu site for your web app: https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net
- Click on **Site extensions** and then click on **Gallery**.
- Search for **Azure Web Apps Disk Usage** site extension.
- Click on **+** icon to install the site extension.
- Once installed, click on the **Restart Site** button. 
  [image: Disk Usage Site Extension]

Now, this should show up under **Installed**. Once installed, the + incon should change to play (**>**) as shown below

[image: Disk Usage Site Extension]

This should take you to the following url: **https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/DiskUsage/** (replace sitename with the name of the web app)

Excluding specific folders from the backup:

There is way to exclude specific folders from your backup.

- Create a file called `_backup.filter`. Place it here: `D:\home\site\wwwroot\_backup.filter`.
- specify the files and folders that you want to exclude in this file
- for example I would add the following to my `_backup.filter` file:

> `\site\wwwroot\Logs`
>
> `\LogFiles`
>
> `\Data`

For more information on how back up works, refer this blogpost: http://zainrizvi.io/2015/06/05/creating-partial-backups-of-your-site-with-azure-web-apps/

If none of this helps, create an **Azure Support** Ticket: [How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)

Answer (score 0):

It is very odd, please firstly check the Web Apps Disk Usage from quota in the web protal and have a try to use following two ways.

1.Scale up your web app then Scale down back. To refresh the web app.

2.I suggest you could create another server plan, then move this web app to that service plan.

If this two ways still don't solve this error.I suggest you could connect to the azure support.